# which asp.net mvc version is compatible with .net framework 4.6

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC applications and I'm building a web project in Visual Studio 2015. My project targets .Net framework 4.6. I want to know which version of ASP.NET MVC is installed with this version of the framework. I have browsed a lot and also looked for answers at the ASP.NET official website, but could not find the answer.

A relevant, but not specific, answer was found at:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157717/what-is-dependency-of-asp-net-mvc-on-net-framework-and-how-to-use-it-with-net

It would be great if someone could list the versions of ASP.NET MVC alongside the versions of the .Net framework they depend upon.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Visual Studio 2017, because it is not dependent on the OS you are using or targeting.

As for your question, which version of MVC are you currently using, and what are the requirements for the project?

If you're building a website that uses Entity Framework or APIs, then I recommend using framework 4.6 and MVC 5 or Core.

According to MSDN:

> **Runtime Changes** Runtime changes affect all apps that are running under
>   the .NET Framework 4.6 and that use a particular feature. **Retargeting
>   Changes** Retargeting changes affect apps that are recompiled to target
>   the .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1, or 4.5.2, or 4.6. They include: Changes
>   in the design-time environment. For example, build tools may emit
>   warnings when previously they did not. Changes in the runtime
>   environment. These affect only apps that specifically target the .NET
>   Framework 4.6. Apps that target previous versions of the .NET
>   Framework behave as they did when running under those versions.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 and .NET Framework 4.6. I have actually built a Lightswitch HTML Application and now adding a User Self Registering functionality. For this task i am using ASP.NET MVC.
Following these two article:
http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/2234/Using-MVC-With-Visual-Studio-LightSwitch.aspx

http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/2235/Allow-LightSwitch-Users-To-Self-Register-and-Change-Passwords-Using-MVC.aspx

Comment: @w_billa - If you already know you're running MVC 5 on .Net 4.6, then what is your question?